# How can I post-process my yolo bounding box data in successive image with correlation(In medical imaging)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, detection, yolo, post-processing

I use yolo algorithm to detect cancer in ct, pet image.  Model is trained with 2D image of ct and pet combined.
Because I trained it with 2d slices, model lost all the correlation between slices. So I want to post-process the result and make the result smooth and more accurate. Nothing too complicated, but to compensate for the obvious mistakes in a series of slices.

Ex) In successive 3 slices, model found cancer correctly in slice 1, 3 but not in 2.

So I want to make up for these situations. What method can I use?